# Creating Cross-References in Scribus

Tags: scribus, cross-reference

I've got a document where I want to add margin notes that display the page number of other relevant sections.

I've been trying to accomplish this using the Insert > Marks > Anchor Mark to mark the sections I want to refer to and then Insert > Marks > Reference to Mark for the reference.

Unfortunately what I'm finding is that this creates two objects - an Anchor object (which seems to always refer to the page where that chapter starts and not the page where the anchor mark was placed) and a "Marks to Anchors" object that refers to an different (and incorrect) page.

The first looks like it's using the first text frame in the linked chain of text frames. I haven't yet been able to suss out how the latter is deriving its page number.

What's the correct way to do cross-referencing using marks in Scribus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be warned: at the time of writing (and asking...) marks are not a stable feature in Scribus!

Use with care.

I did a test:

- Create a text chain that starts on page 1 and continues on page 2.
- In the chained frame on page 2 insert an "Anchor mark" called "test".
- Create a frame on page 1.
- In the new frame insert a reference to mark to test.
- The page number is indeed 1 instead of 2

I've [opened a ticket](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=16216) in the Scribus bug tracker.

Comment: As you might have read in the comments in the ticket, the bug is not easy to solve.